# I have an array which I need to extract only number

Tags: javascript

var price = [ Rs 299, Rs 499, Rs 899, Rs 199 ];

I need to store this [ 299, 499, 899, 199] in an array.

Comment: What did you try, what went wrong with that, do you see any errors. Please hare your code. People here will be able to help you better..

Comment: I can't able to store the resultant array in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your array elements are strings this should work

```js
let array = [ 'Rs 299', 'Rs 499', 'Rs 899', 'Rs 199' ]
console.log(array.map(elem => Number(elem.split(' ')[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use string `match()` here for a regex based solution:

```js
var array = ["Rs 299", "Rs 499", "Rs 899", "Rs 199"];
var nums = array.map(x => Number(x.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)[0]));
console.log(nums);
```

Comment: `/\d+/` works as too.

Comment: @Brother58697 ... but `\d+` won't cover decimal values, which could be a possibility for currency or price amounts.

Comment: Good point! Now to learn more about non capture groups!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use a non capturing group? `\d+(\.\d+)?` works fine.

Comment: We don't need that capture group, so it is preferable to just turn it off.

Comment: Im not sure I see what you mean. The decimals get matched either way in both cases.

Comment: @Brother58697 I would encourage you to review the basics of regex.